# How do I get Internet Explorer to save this response as a file?

Tags: internet-explorer, asp.net-web-api, download, asp.net-web-api2

I a have the following code in a WebAPI2 web service:

```
...
var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
    Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(byte_data))
};
resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
resp.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") {
    FileName = "MyFile.csv"
};

return resp;
```

In Firefox and Chrome, this (correctly) saves as a .csv file in the download location.  In IE, it opens a blank page, and does nothing else I can tell; the response viewed in developer tools has the correct content.

The same happens with both IE 9 and 11.

Any ideas how I can solve this or troubleshoot it more?

Thanks.

Comment: it should be somewhere in the settings, privacy settings as I remember.